# Unable to create account in Hyperledger sawtooth seth (Ethereum)

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to deploy a smart contract on the sawtooth network. While creating account with the command : It is getting a timeout.

```
seth account create --nonce=0 --wait myalias
```

Error: Problem submitting account creation transaction: Transaction was submitted, but client timed out before it was committed.

Can we increase the timeout or what can be the possible solution for the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens if you did not have `--wait` on the command line, so the client to wait for the commit response.

Another thing you can do is check that all the client services are running (listed in the docker-compose.yaml file if you are using Docker).